# How to cite a UN treaty (BibTex entry)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I need to add to my bibliography (in LaTeX, using Bibtex) an entry for the Paris Agreement (2015):
https://treaties.un.org/pages/ViewDetails.aspx?src=TREATY&mtdsg_no=XXVII-7-d&chapter=27&clang=_en

However, I have been unable to find any BibTeX-style (or, for that matter, any citation format) for how to cite such a UN treaty. What would be the right format?

Comment: Not sure whether it's better suited to Academia.SE. if it is, please feel free to migrate the question.

Comment: Here's what the APA blog has to say: http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2013/09/citing-treaties-and-other-international-agreements.html  I think this covers most of the things. The APA is an author-year style, so if you're using any author-year style their guidelines would probably work, assuming that most journals don't have a specified style for them. If you are working in a legal citation framework, however, things may be quite different. If you only need this very rarely, then using a `misc` entry type would probably be simplest.

Comment: For how to create custom citation and references for legislation in `biblatex` see [What is best practice re. handling legal sources with Biblatex/Biber for disciplines other than law?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437824/2693).

Comment: The exact form for your `.bib` entry will probably have to depend not only on the desired output, but also on the (BibTeX/`biblatex`) bibliography style you use in your document. For the occasional use `@misc` as suggested by Allan Munn seems the obvious choice, but the exact content of the fields may have to be tweaked a bit between styles.

Comment: For `biblatex` `@misc{paris,
  title   = {Paris Agreement},
  date    = {2015-12-12},
  note    = {UNTC XXVII 7.d},
}` would work reasonably well - it wouldn't give you the exact APA style output, but it would probably be close enough for most other intents and purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: there is nothing exactly on point ready to hand. It can be approximated quickly, though.

Slightly longer answer:

Depends on what information you need to pass on to your reader.

What will come into play is choosing from a combination of already existing biblatex styles and the entry types they support.

For example, for general purposes:

The `oxnotes` biblatex style has a `@legal` bib entry type, and `piltreaty` subentrytype, which handles the legally relevant dates. URLs are not really part of that picture (yet).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@legal{paris,
entrysubtype = {piltreaty},
title = {Paris Agreement},
shorthand = {Paris Agreement},
execution = {adopted=2015-12-12 and inforce=2016-11-04},
pagination = {article},
journaltitle = {United Nations Treaty Collection, Chapter XXVII 7. d},
url = {https://treaties.un.org/pages/ViewDetails.aspx?src=TREATY&mtdsg_no=XXVII-7-d&chapter=27&clang=_en},
urldate = {2019-03-28}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oxnotes,
        isourls=true,
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Oxnotes Style, @legal entry type}
As stated in the \citetitle[Article 4, paragraph 2]{paris}: ``Parties shall pursue domestic mitigation measures, ...''

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: oxnotes treaty]

The `apa` style, by contrast, has a `@data` entry type which looks promising: it does a nice url, but its dates are limited (more publication-related), and there is not a cascade of them.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}


@data{paris,
title = {Paris Agreement},
type = {UN Treaty},
entrysubtype = {Treaty No. XXVII-7-d},
%shorthand = {Paris Agreement},
day = {12},
month  = {12},
year = {2015},
organization = {United Nations},
 url ={https://treaties.un.org/pages/ViewDetails.aspx?src=TREATY&mtdsg_no=XXVII-7-d&chapter=27&clang=_en},
  urlday = {28},
  urlmonth = {3},
  urlyear = {2019},
  author = {},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{APA Style, @data entry type}
As stated in the \citetitle[Article 4, paragraph 2]{paris}: ``Parties shall pursue domestic mitigation measures, ...''

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: apa treaty]

To get an idea of the effort needed to adapt a style, adding a url to the `oxnotes` legal entry turns out to be a one-line change, since all the heavy lifting and pre-work (field definition, assignment and allocation; date parsing and processing; options processing; string constant definition) has already been done.

We just get the already-formatted and packaged `url+urldate` and "bung it in" at the end (literally) of the bit that prints the formatted legal entry item in the bibliography (code from the foundational `oxref.dbx` file and copied into our document tex file's preamble:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{legal}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\explanatorynote}{%
    \printfield[default]{title}%
    \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  }{%
    \iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\parliamentarytype}{%
      \usebibmacro{legal:parliamentary}%
    }{%
      \usebibmacro{treatycitation}}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \printfield[default]{note}
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%=========== this line
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@legal{paris,
entrysubtype = {piltreaty},
title = {Paris Agreement},
shorthand = {Paris Agreement},
execution = {adopted=2015-12-12 and inforce=2016-11-04},
pagination = {article},
journaltitle = {United Nations Treaty Collection, Chapter XXVII 7. d},
url = {https://treaties.un.org/pages/ViewDetails.aspx?src=TREATY&mtdsg_no=XXVII-7-d&chapter=27&clang=_en},
urldate = {2019-03-28}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}


%=============================
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oxnotes,
        isourls=true,
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



%=============================
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{legal}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\explanatorynote}{%
    \printfield[default]{title}%
    \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  }{%
    \iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\parliamentarytype}{%
      \usebibmacro{legal:parliamentary}%
    }{%
      \usebibmacro{treatycitation}}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \printfield[default]{note}
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%=========== this line
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}




\begin{document}

\section{Oxnotes Style, @legal entry type (mod)}
As stated in the \citetitle[Article 4, paragraph 2]{paris}: ``Parties shall pursue domestic mitigation measures, ...''

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: oxnotes legal with url]

To change the `apa` style to be able to handle the dates is TML (too many lines) - for me, anyway :) . Doable, certainly. But not a five-minute job. 
 Although, thinking about it for a moment, the dates could go in as extra, individual fields, and then get formatted, and with bibstrings added. So, six minutes, then.

Comment: Very nice answer. Incidentally, as the author of `oscola`, which is (largely) used by `oxnotes` for legal material, I suppose I was responsible for not including the URL in treaties. The documentation suggests that it's a deliberate decision; but I can see an argument for having it, and that argument might be *stronger* for `oxnotes` and `oscola` because whereas practising lawyers ware likely to know how to find a treaty given the reference, others might not.

Answer (score 3):

I regularly cite UN treaties as an international law researcher, and so far the best footnote style I've found is `oscola` and the best endnote style is `oxnum` (both based on Biblatex). They conveniently use the same bibliographic format with the `piltreaty` subtype and treaty-specific fields. The relevant entry in my `.bib` file looks like this:

```
@legal{ParisAgreement,
  entrysubtype = {piltreaty},
  title        = {Paris Agreement},
  execution    = {adopted=2015-12-12 and inforce=2016-11-04},
  pagination   = {article},
  reporter     = {A.T.S.},
  series       = {2016},
  pages        = {24},
  note         = {},
  shorttitle   = {Paris Agreement},
}
```

This produces "Paris Agreement (adopted 12 Dec. 2015, entered into force 4 Nov. 2016) ATS 2016 24." as a full reference. The url is not typically added in legal citations, but could be done as described by Cicada's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481901/274637).

In this case I refer to the Australian Treaty Series (ATS), but only because the Paris Agreement has not been published in a United Nations Treaty Series (UNTS) volume yet. The UNTS online url for the Paris Agreement is [this](https://treaties.un.org/Pages/showDetails.aspx?objid=0800000280458f37&clang=_en), and it will show an UNTS vol and page number when it's published there. UNTS is the main UN treaty publication, not the one you point to in your question. If you do want to cite that one, the series name is "Multilateral Treaties Deposited with the Secretary General", abbreviated MTDSG.

You can find more examples and explanations in my Gitlab repo on [treaty references](https://gitlab.com/martinakunz/treaty-references) with python scripts that generate .bib files from data scraped from UNTS and ATS. It's easy generate a project-specific `.bib` file if e.g. a particular publication/submission is not supposed to include the date of entry into force of a treaty, just remove the relevant information from the bibliographic entry.

N.B.: This is answer is for the best case scenario where you can choose the citation style yourself or the required style is identical or very similar to what `oscola` and `oxnum` (or other `oxref` packages) produce.