# Will [lawcite] soon implement a Bluebook legal citation style?

Tags: biblatex, legal-style

Two years ago the Question [What is best practice re. handling legal sources with Biblatex/Biber for disciplines other than law?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437824/what-is-best-practice-re-handling-legal-sources-with-biblatex-biber-for-discipl/481840#481840) received numerous thoughtful comments, perhaps helping to inspire the `lawcite` package ([github.com/texcicada/lawcite](https://github.com/texcicada/lawcite)).  As I understand it, `lawcite` is intended to be general enough to accommodate any (?) legal citation style and already has at least partial support for AGLC (Australian), McGill (Canadian), and Modern Law Review.

Can Bluebook be far behind?

Comment: Hrmmm, I don't think this is a particularly appropriate (for lack of a better word) question for this site. This is essentially asking about the future development (plans) of a particular package. The only good answer here can come from the developer themselves. I think it would be a better idea to open a feature request at https://github.com/texcicada/lawcite/issues and see where it goes or to contact the `lawcite` maintainer by other means and ask about their plans.

Comment: I hope to alert more TeX.SE readers to ```lawcite```.  Only by thorough searching and reading of comments on questions did I find it myself.  But I will try to make this Q more appropriate (ditto).

Comment: Hmm, if your aim is to advertise the package, maybe it would be possible to ask a question about legal citations and self-answer it with a fully working and compilable example document. That would help people getting started using `lawcite`. In its current form the question is pretty much off-topic here, since it asks about the future development of a package.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the future directions of development of a particular TeX package and as such highly speculative.